# get request with axios where page renders data with a delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, axios

I am trying to get the html of a page using axios but it appears that this page has a **loading** functionality and the result I get is the loading page and not the results after loading.

```
axios.get(page).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data) // returns loading state of webpage
})
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would use something like phantomJS that emulates a browser